# A question about specific and general terms for paraverbal resources used in songs?

Tags: technique

Does the part of a certain song, when the singer produce animal-like sounds
or more extreme-emotional sounds or object-like sounds or tribal sounds,
receive some denomination ?

For example I know that some type of sounds has their own denomination
like Guttural sounds, Tuvan throat singing or Beatboxing.

I am not searching stuff like "Linkin Park - In The End | Ten Second Songs 20 Style Cover",
which is more centered to the variation of style on how a song is produced.

For example, there is a song, that went viral some time ago (by Muslim Magomayev or Eduard Khil)
where all the song is non-word sounds. A notably example could be "Claron McFadden: Singing the primal mystery". More like this, but not necessarily during
all the song. It could be very brief intervals of a certain song.
Some famous artist that comes to my mind is Michael Jackson.

Not much ago I was listening these two songs
Skyrim - Lindsey Stirling & Peter Hollens
Franco "El Gorila" Ft. O'Neill - Nobody Like You

The reason to name them is that is not so easily noticeable in all songs,
when there is human voice involved.

I little research shows results in wikipedia like Emotional prosody,
Paralanguage, Pharyngeal consonant, Prosodic unit,
Prosody (linguistics), Place of articulation, Onomatopoeia, Uvular consonant

Really, not necessarily in music, it could be sounds involved in some "musical"
reaction in social situations, but I am more curious in a musical context, or
when applied to musical context from some other context.

It is not necessary that has to have a written counterpart or representation.

I am not sure if there are more exact or concrete words or denominations,
or if they are taken into account in standard musical vocabulary( where part
of the words comes from italian language).

I would like some keywords to keep the research.

For quite some time I have had this doubt.

(some useful tag to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word that comes to mind is '[vocalise](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vocalise)', which in its second definition seems to mean what you are looking for.

[Scat singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) is also related, although is much more specific in its definition. Scat singing in popular music today comes off as cheesy to many.

Comment: still researching, in principle could be a mix between vocalize and onomatopeias, but I am not sure